# Why does my ios app flash on start although I have launch image

Tags: ios

I have a simple html based app (targeting ios7) with a few html files. I supplied the launch images for 1x and 2x.

When the app launches it first displays the image, then a white flash and only after that the html file.

Details for the images:

```
1x image - 1024 x 768px
2x image - 2048 x 1496px
```

xcode did not accept the 1536px image so I used the 1496px one. Now it is complaining that it should be 1536px.

Considering that the whole purpose of the launch images is to prevent that flash, I cannot understand why this happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance that flash is the blank `UIWebView` before loading the content?

Comment: set a breakpoint at the `UIWebView` delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, if it gets called after the flash is finished than it's probably the `uiwebview` who cause that.